# Headless Mac Mini can display 2560x1440 after being plugged into, then unplugged from an external monitor, but only goes up to 1920x1080 after restart

Tags: display, mac-mini, thunderbolt, displayport, resolution

I am using a Late 2012 Mac Mini exclusively through Screen Sharing on my MacBook (Both on 10.13.4). The only way I could get the Mac Mini to full resolution was to:

1. Close connection from my MacBook to the Mac Mini on MacOS's native Screen Sharing utility
2. Plug Mini DisplayPort adapter into Mac Mini (leading to an Apple Thunderbolt Display)
3. Immediately unplug it
4. Log back in on MacBook

When I restart the Mac Mini, the display immediately returns to 1280x1024. The highest I can get it to is 1920x1080, and that's while holding ⌥ (Alt/Option) in Display Settings. Is there a way I can get it to 2560x1440 without having to arbitrarily plug it into/unplug it from the display?